# How I can keep current screen process while user move to another screen Flutter

Tags: flutter, background-process

If user upload image but he don't havr to stay in the same page ..
Could we use
Navigator.pop(context);
Or what us the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Use State management, it will keep your state.

My recommendation is Provider, Bloc but you can use any.